# Were there any role-playing games in medieval times?

Tags: middle-ages

**Note:** This might be a bit of a naïve question, but I imagine it is a valid one. I am not a historian.

That is, were there any "standard" activities (with a set of rules or other concrete description), be them board-based or not, that involved acting/role-playing with the intent of mutual entertainment?

Sure, theatrics themselves are very ancient, but are usually intended as a presentation to a public, not for the entertainment of the actors themselves.

**So, was any kind of roleplaying game practiced?**

Comment: Trivially no - as the accoutrements necessary require existence of a printing press not invented until the 15th century. The widespread literacy and numeracy required to play the games followed both invention of the printing press and the introduction of national public education systems in the mid 19th century. People played musical instruments and acted in plays instead - and the latter was widely seen as *beneath polite society*.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens fair enough, that's probably the answer. However, just to clarify: I'm not just asking for the "modern" pen&paper RPG (since that evidently only appeared much much later), just roleplaying in general.

Comment: The [*kriegspiel*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriegsspiel_(wargame)) was invented by the Prussian General Staff in the mid-19th century - without that concept, and the much later popularization of *wargames* by [Charles S. Roberts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_S._Roberts) with the [Avalon ill Game Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalon_Hill), there would be no roleplaying games.

Comment: I can't imagine a society in which children didn't play "pretend" with each other. (That may just be my assumption, however.) It seems to me that the question wouldn't be whether there was role-playing as such, as whether there was role-playing with rules, whether those rules were transmitted orally or in writing.

Comment: Precisely, @bgvaughan.

Comment: Would charades count?  Don't know if it goes back to medieval times, but was around in early 19th century Britain (mentioned in e.g. Austen's "Emma").

Comment: @jamesqf Your mention of Jane Austen reminded me of the Brontë sisters (I keep getting her mixed up with them). From childhood, the Brontës collaborated on an imaginary world, [Gondal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gondal_(fictional_country)). (Still 19th century, not medieval, though I like to imagine the Brontës would have been the greatest dungeon masters ever.)

Comment: Does chess count?

Comment: @liftarn I don't know. Did chess players in that period pretend to actually be the warring parties they played? At least in modern chess, this isn't the case. It's a game about a battle, but it's hardly ever played with _roleplaying_ attached to it.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Don't forget H.G. Wells' "Little Wars".

Comment: Relevant XKCD: https://xkcd.com/593/

Comment: @AndrewGrimm it was me presenting that comic to a group of friends what sparked this question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Medieval, and way older; as [Saturnalia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturnalia), [Carnival](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnival#Origin) or whatever the name your culture had for it. Festivities about role reversal seem to be abundant.

For example, for Saturnalia:

> Saturnalia was characterized by role reversals and behavioral license. Slaves were treated to a banquet of the kind usually enjoyed by their masters. Ancient sources differ on the circumstances: some suggest that master and slave dined together, while others indicate that the slaves feasted first, or that the masters actually served the food. The practice might have varied over time.

Carnivals later developed on top of that, but there are also some local festivities that involve not role but gender reversal, for example [mumming<sup>1</sup> in England and some celebrations of Saint Agatha](https://books.google.es/books?id=KcD7nVelXJgC&lpg=PA75&ots=_Bgl0HupPu&dq=saint%20agatha%20role%20reversal&hl=es&pg=PA74#v=onepage&q&f=false)

And, of course, [this other pagan festivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halloween).

---

<sup>1</sup>Don't ask me what exactly "mumming" is, I found it while looking for the Saint Agatha festivities.

Comment: [Mumming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mummers_play) is a style of dramatic performance, which seems to have originated in the British Isles and spread from there.

Answer (score 2):

Chess and its predecessors are board-based battle games in which players assume the role of various military figures (the specific roles involved depend on which set of pieces are in use). Today's game was standardized in Europe towards the end of the medieval period. It does not require nor prohibit "acting" and "theatrics".

Comment: The fact that it doesn't require any acting _to be able to play_, kind of puts off most board games. Otherwise, most games would indeed classify as roleplaying simply due to their mechanics having been created based on some real concept. Anyways, thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Kroltan do the so-called role-playing games actually require acting? As I understand it, Dungeon Masters that can improvise are preferred, but unless I am mistaken, there is no requirement that they act theatrically.